# Mongoose connect Promise callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, callback

While testing execution of callback (continuation) supplied in `.then(...)` method of `mongoose.connect(...)` Promise, I find that this is obviously not scheduled on the microtask queue as expected from Promise.
Here is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function sleep(time) {
    const now = Date.now();
    while(now + time > Date.now()) {}
}

console.log('START');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playground')
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
        });

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("setTimeout() - callback queue");
}, 0);

Promise.resolve("A").then(result => {
    sleep(1000);
    console.log("1. Resolved Promise:", result);
});

Promise.resolve("B").then(result => {
    sleep(1000);
    console.log("2. Resolved Promise:", result);
});

console.log('END');
```

After running above code using Nodejs (version 16.9.1) I get following output:

*START*
*END*
*1. Resolved Promise: A*
*2. Resolved Promise: B*
*setTimeout() - callback queue*
*Connected to MongoDB*

As `mongoose.connect(..)` returns a Promise, shouldn't its callback (continuation):
`console.log('Connected to MongoDB');` be also scheduled on a microtask queue and therefore executed before `setTimeout()`'s callback which is scheduled on lower priority callback (task) queue?

I am using mongoose 6.0.12

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am simply doing some tests, researchs, some comparisons between .net's Task and JS Promise. Nothing special, nothing too big. I want to be sure that I have correct understanding of basic concepts before building something. Verifying that statements in JS's and mongoose's documentation about Promise and their callback scheduling is indeed how it gets executed. Maybe some Promise's callbacks are not scheduled on microtask queue or mongoose's Promise callback is actually regular callback that is scheduled on callback (task) queue like setTimeout's callback?